# I don't know how to use flipanimation correctly

Tags: animation, add-on, mirror

I have an issue with "flip animation" add-on, I flipped my animation, but it doesn't flip it well, it's kind of deformed, like the X axis is rotated off 90°, just look at this image...[image][image] this is before and after I used flip animation add-on...